# Prove existence of limit points for a sequence of solutions to ODE Cauchy problems - Scuola Normale Superiore admission test, 2018

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This problem is from the 2018 admission test to Scuola Normale Superiore in Pisa, Italy. I am having trouble with the second question.

**Problem:** Let $V^1, V^2: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be two Lipschitz-continuous vector fields. Given $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ consider, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the vector fields $V_n: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ defined as

$$V_n(t, x) = V^1(x) + \chi(nt)(V^2(x) - V^1(x))$$

where $\chi: \mathbb{R} \to \{0,1\}$ is the $1$-periodic extension of the characteristic function $\chi_{]0,\lambda[}: [0,1[ \to \{0,1\}$.

For $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\gamma_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^N$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
    x' = V_n(t,x) \\
    x(0) = x_0
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that:

$1.)$ $\gamma_n$ exists and is unique, in the class of piecewise $C^1$ functions.

$2.)$ The sequence $\{\gamma_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has limit points $\gamma$ in $C([-T,T];\mathbb{R}^N)$ for every $T>0$.

$3.)$ The sequence $\{\gamma_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, and determine the differential equation that the limit function satisfies.

**My work so far**:

$1.)$ Observe that
$$
V_n(t,x)=
\begin{cases}
    V^2(x) & \text{if } \frac{k}{n} < t < \frac{k+\lambda}{n} \text{ for some $k \in \mathbf{N}$}, \\
    V^1(x) & \text{if } \frac{k+\lambda}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{k+1}{n} \text{ for some $k \in \mathbf{N}$}
\end{cases}
$$

so the Cauchy problem can be restated as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
    x'=\begin{cases}
        V^2(x) & \text{if } \frac{k}{n} < t < \frac{k+\lambda}{n}, \\
        V^1(x) & \text{if } \frac{k+\lambda}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{k+1}{n},
    \end{cases} \\
    x(0)=x_0
\end{cases} \quad \quad (1)
$$

Since $V^1$ is Lipschitz-continuous there exists $L_1>0$ such that $\|V^1(x)-V^1(y) \| < L_1\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in \textbf{R}^N$, from which follows that $\|V^1(x)\| \leq \max\{L_1, \|V^1(0)\|\}(1+\|x\|)$  for all $x\in \textbf{R}^N$. We may now apply the global existence and uniqueness theorem to the problem $\begin{cases}
    x'= V^1(x) \\
    x(0)=x_0
\end{cases}$ and obtain a unique solution defined on $\textbf{R}$. It is now easy to construct a piecewise $C^1$ function $\gamma: \textbf{R} \to \textbf{R}^N$ that is a solution to $(1)$, but I can't think of a quick way to write it down. This solution must also be unique because, by construction, it is unique on each of the intervals $ \left]\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+\lambda}{n}\right[$ and $\left [\frac{k+\lambda}{n},\frac{k+1}{n} \right]$.

$2.)$ My first idea was to use Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, however I can't seem to prove either that $\{\gamma_n\}_n$
is uniformy bounded nor that it is uniformly equicontinous. I'm not having any more luck with proving point-wise convergence. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

$2.)$ Gronwall's lemma can be used to prove that $\{\gamma_n\}_n$ is uniformly bounded; once this fact is proven it it easy to show that $\{\gamma_n'\}_n$ is uniformly bounded too, from which follows that $\{\gamma_n\}_n$ is uniformly equi-continous.
Fix $n \in \textbf{N}$ and observe that, for all $t \in [-T,T]$:

\begin{align*}
      \|\gamma_n(t)\| &\leq \|x_0\|+\left |\int_0^t ||V_n(t, \gamma_n(s)) \|\, ds \right| \\
      & \leq \|x_0\| + \left| \int_0^t \| V^1(\gamma_n(s))\|+\|V^2(\gamma_n(s))\| \, ds \right| \\
  \end{align*}

Since $V^1$ is Lipschitz-continous there exists $L_1>0$ such that $\|V^1(\gamma_n(t))-V^1(0)\| < L_1\|\gamma_n(t)\|$ for all $t \in [-T,T]$. Using the the inverse triangle inequality on the left-hand side we obtain

$$\forall \, t \in [-T,T] \quad \|V^1(\gamma_n(t))\|<\|V^1(0)\| + L_1\|\gamma_n(t)\|$$

Similarily for $V^2$ there exists a $L_2>0$ such that

$$\forall \, t \in [-T,T] \quad \|V^2(\gamma_n(t))\|<\|V^2(0)\| + L_2\|\gamma_n(t)\|$$

which allows us to write

\begin{align*}
    \|x_0\| + \left |\int_0^t \| V^1(\gamma_n(s))\|+\|V^2(\gamma_n(s))\| \, ds \right | &\leq \|x_0\| + \left |\int_0^t A+B\|(\gamma_n(s))\| \, ds \right |\\
    &\leq \|x_0\|+AT+B\left |\int_0^t \|\gamma_n(s)\| \, ds \right |
\end{align*}

where $A:=\|V^1(0)\|+\|V^2(0)\|$ and $B:=L_1+L_2$. We may now apply Gronwall's lemma to $\|\gamma_n(t)\|$ to obtain

$$\|\gamma_n(t)\| \leq (\|x_0\|+AT)e^{BT}:=M$$

Since $M$ does not depend on $n$ this proves that $\{\gamma_n\}_n$ is uniformly bounded.

To show that $\{\gamma'_n\}_n$ is uniformly bounded, fix $n \in \textbf{N}$ and observe that

\begin{align*}
    \|\gamma_n'(t)\| &\leq \|V^1(\gamma_n(t))\|+\|V^2(\gamma_n(t))\| \\
    &\leq \sup_{x \in \gamma_n([-T,T]}(\|V^1(x)\|+\|V^2(x)\|) \\
    &\leq \sup_{\|x\| \leq M}(\|V^1(x)\|+\|V^2(x)\|)
\end{align*}

which does not depend on $n$. This means that $\{\gamma_n\}_n$ is equi-Lipschitz, therefore uniformly equi-continous. By Arzelà-Ascoli theorem $\{\gamma_n\}_n$ has a limit point in $C([-T,T], \textbf{R}^N)$.

Comment: See [here](https://www.sns.it/sites/default/files/2021-04/2010%202019%20prove%20scienze%204%20anno.pdf) the problem in it's original language.

Comment: My intuitive guess for point 3 is that the limit function $\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n$ should satisfy (a.e. (?)) the differential equation $\gamma'=U(\gamma)$ with $U$ being the vector  field given by $U(x)=\lambda V^2(x)+(1-\lambda) V^1(x)$. However I haven't found any way to prove it so far (excluding the easy case of constant fields $V^i$ and piecewise linear $\gamma_n$).